# TYPO3 mod.php access without beeing logged in (Extbase)

Tags: typo3, fluid, google-cloud-messaging, extbase

i'm writing a TYPO3 extension with *extbase & fluid* which should be able to send push notifications to android devices.

For this i need to catch a **POST** request from google which contains a *registerID* as a *string*. So, i had the idea to send the POST to the **mod.php** including the parameter "*controller*" and "*action*". Like: http://mywebsite.com/typo3/mod.php?M_web_myextension&action=register&controller=Register ....something like that. Because i need to handle the registrationID within my Controller.

But the mod.php is only accessible for logged-in users or admins and redirects to the login-formular if someone is not logged-in. So my Android-App replies: FileNotFoundException.

How can i send POST-data to my extbase controller from outside TYPO3?

Or how can i make the mod.php accessible for everyone even outside of TYPO3?

Any other suggestions welcome!

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Operating with `typo3/mod.php` seems to be a wrong idea as it **requires** an active backend login user. And you **can't** make it accessible for anyone.

Instead you need to build a `Front-end` plugin which allows for connections without authentication and then `authenticate` and `authorize` your user by some token hidden in the form.

Of course you should use some encryption on the Android and TYPO3 level for the credentials passed in the form, otherwise every body will be able to falsify it.

Comment: Thank you biesior. That's a good idea! I also had the thought to handle that via a frontend-plugin after all. I'll try that. 

Thank you!